# How can I get text in an HTML tr (table row) to center?

Tags: c#, html, css, centering, text-align

I'm building some HTML in a StringBuilder like so:

```
builder.Append("<tr align='center' valign='top' class=\"skyBlueBackground textAlignCenter\">");
List<String> columnHeadings = GetColumnHeadings(monthCount, _begindate);
foreach (String s in columnHeadings)
{
    if (s.Equals("Grand Total"))
    {
        builder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top' class=\"forestGreenBackground whiteText\"><b>");
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'><b>");
    }
    builder.Append(s);
    builder.Append("</b></td>");
}
builder.Append("</tr>");
```

Although I've got a class for centering text:

```
builder.Append("</style>");
. . .
builder.Append(".textAlignCenter { text-align: center; }");
builder.Append("</style>");
```

...the text is aligned left; it works other than that (skyblue background), it just stays magnetized to the left:

[image]

What must I do to get the text to center?

Comment: Well the text is aligned left because you have a: align='left' attribute + if you wish to center the text of a cell, apply the centering class on that specific cell. Not sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: The attribute on td cell is causing the text to force align to the left. Remove it. <td align='left'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either set the textAlignCenter on the TD, not the TR or change the CSS definition to:

```
builder.Append(".textAlignCenter td { text-align: center; }");
```

And you should remove the explicit "align='left'" from your TD because that will still overrule the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for how to vertically align the text, you could use the `vertical-align` CSS property. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for more info.

You could also use the `valign` attribute, but it is deprecated in HTML5 and it is not a recommended approach.

Comment: Thanks; I added vertical-align: middle; to the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply, you have created correctly the css class property .textAlignCenter, but your attribute align="left" on the `<td>` has style priority.

---

I think you can do two solutions:

1. Put the class .textAlignCenter on the **td** you want to align
   center.
2. Remove the align="center" of the **td** and add a css like
   this:

   ```
   tr td {text-align:left}

   tr td.textAlignCenter {text-align:center}
   ```

---

With this last solution you overwrite the last style.